# How to make all buttons function from a template literal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the buttons display type to block, but only the first button works. Here is my code:

```
const descriptions = ['Hi', 'Bonjour', 'Guten Tag', 'Hola', 'Zdravstvuyte', 'Nǐn hǎo', 'Salve', 'Konnichiwa', 'Olá', 'Goddag', 'Shikamoo', 'Goedendag']

//Loop created to do its magic for the array
for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    images.push(`<div><img src="${links[i]}"> <button id="myBtn">More info</button><div id='descriptions' style="display: none;">${descriptions[i]}</div></div>`)
}

//Images have been dynamically added!
$images.innerHTML += images.join(' ')

//Event listener so the buttons can function
$images.addEventListener('click', function (event){
    if (event.target.id == 'myBtn') {
       document.getElementById('descriptions').style.display = 'block'
       console.log('button clicked')
        
    }
```

Comment: Don't repeat HTML id attributes. ID attributes by nature are designed to be unique. The browser can't tell which button you pressed.

Comment: *You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.* https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

AS mentioned don't use multiple IDs. IDs must be unique, that is what makes them IDs

Use a sane data structure instead of multiple arrays.

The data is iterated once, do the work there, using a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), so the DOM is not continually updated.

Finally, use CSS not inline styles adding an active class on button click.

```js
//Use a sane data structure instead of multiple arrays
images = [
  {"link": "Hi.jpg", 
   "description": "Hi"
   },
   {"link": "Bonjour.jpg", 
   "description": "Bonjour"
   },
   {"link": "Guten-Tag.jpg", 
   "description": "Guten Tag"
   },
   {"link": "Hola.jpg", 
   "description": "Hola"
   },
   {"link": "Zdravstvuyte.jpg", 
   "description": "Zdravstvuyte"
   },
   {"link": "Nǐn-hǎo.jpg", 
   "description": "Nǐn hǎo"
   },
   {"link": "Salve.jpg", 
   "description": "Salve"
   },
   {"link": "Konnichiwa.jpg", 
   "description": "Konnichiwa"
   },
   {"link": "Olá.jpg", 
   "description": "Olá"
   },
   {"link": "Goddag.jpg", 
   "description": "Goddag"
   },
   {"link": "Shikamoo.jpg", 
   "description": "Shikamoo"
   },
   {"link": "Goedendag.jpg", 
   "description": "Goedendag"
   }
];

//Get the image
$images = document.getElementById("images");
//Create  frament to do the work in
var fragment = new DocumentFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = "";
//Iterate the data, never hard code a number here, use the length of your data array
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  //update the fragment
  fragment.innerHTML += `<div><img src="${images[i].link}"> <button class="myBtn">More info</button><div class='descriptions'>${images[i].description}</div></div>`;
}

//UPdate the host elemen
$images.innerHTML =fragment.innerHTML;
//Event listener
$images.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      //If myBtn clicked
      if (event.target.matches('.myBtn')) {
        //Find parent div
        let parent = event.target.closest("div");
        //Find descriptions element and add active class
        parent.querySelector(".descriptions").classList.add("active");        

      }
})
```

```css
.descriptions:not(.active) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

don't use multiple `id` read comment above, use `class` instead. you need is `.nextElementSibling` to select element after the button.

```js
const links = ["Hi.jpg", "Bonjour.jpg", "Guten-Tag.jpg", "Hola.jpg", "Zdravstvuyte.jpg", "Nǐn-hǎo.jpg", "Salve.jpg", "Konnichiwa.jpg", "Olá.jpg", "Goddag.jpg", "Shikamoo.jpg", "Goedendag.jpg"];
const descriptions = ['Hi', 'Bonjour', 'Guten Tag', 'Hola', 'Zdravstvuyte', 'Nǐn hǎo', 'Salve', 'Konnichiwa', 'Olá', 'Goddag', 'Shikamoo', 'Goedendag']
images = [];

$images = document.body;

//Loop created to do its magic for the array
for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
  images.push(`<div><img src="${links[i]}"> <button class="myBtn">More info</button><div id='descriptions' style="display: none;">${descriptions[i]}</div></div>`)
}

//Images have been dynamically added!
$images.innerHTML += images.join(' ')

//Event listener so the buttons can function
$images.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.classList.contains('myBtn')) {
        event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
        console.log('button clicked')

      }
})
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: *you can use multiple id but it's not recommended* No, you cannot not do that. It clearly violates the specification, and writing invalid code as per the spec is never acceptable, nor is it wise.